# Enum or constants in BigQuery?

Tags: google-bigquery

Is it possible to create constants or enumerations in BigQuery in order to use them when making queries (selects)?

Example:

```
select *
from table
where column = __CONST_VALUE_TO_FILTER
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When using BigQuery scripting, the DECLARE statement allows you to create constants as follows:

```
DECLARE variable_name[, ...] [variable_type] [DEFAULT expression];
```

According to that, in case you wanted to use as a filtering condition, you can use something similar to:

```
DECLARE x, y, z INT64 DEFAULT 0;
DECLARE var DEFAULT (SELECT item FROM other_table LIMIT 1);

select *
from table
where column = x;
```

Check the documentation on [1] to know more about the DECLARE and other StandardSQL statements.

[1] -
https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/standard-sql/scripting#declare

Answer (score 0):

We frequently use the below syntax:

```
DECLARE var_timestamp_start DEFAULT '2020-01-01 00:00:00';
DECLARE var_timestamp_end DEFAULT '2020-01-01 00:00:00';
DECLARE var_countries DEFAULT [1,10,50];

select var_timestamp_start,var_timestamp_end,var_countries;
```

of course you are able to use them in Where filters as well